# Cannot browse web server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, iptables

I have a server running Apache on Centos 6.4 and I cannot get to browse the box - SSH works fine and as does FTP but nothing http will work.

httpd is started, SELinux is not running and I have opened port 80 in iptables but I cannot connect - I can ping etc but not load anything. httpd.conf is also set to allow all on port 80 and error_log doesn't contain any errors.

What else have I missed?

Comment: What happens if you telnet to port 80 on the server?

Comment: Check your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file for the "Order Allow, Deny, allow from all" section.

Comment: how about to look in error log? is there any backend mysql/php etc, or you are trying to get default apache welcome page?

Comment: Check error logs

Comment: There is nothing in the error logs as mentioned above - telnet fails with "Connecting to X.X.X.X... Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed"

Comment: httpd.conf has "Order allow,deny Allow from all"

Comment: Please supply the output of the next commands:
# iptables -L
# netstat -anp |grep LISTEN
# tail -n 15 /var/log/httpd/access_log

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use curl on your IP

e.g.

`curl --verbose http:// (YOUR_IP)`

You will see http requests / responses

Comment: * About to connect() to X.X.X.X port 80 (#0)
*   Trying X.X.X.X... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host